# Rename recursively exluding the current directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rename

I use this command to rename files recursively:

```
find -iname \*.bak | rename 's/.bak/.old/'
```

But I want to exclude the current directory. Example:

```
.bak
dir1/.bak
dir2/.bak
...
```

After I want this:

```
.bak
dir1/.old
dir2/.old
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
find -iname \*.bak -not -path "./.bak" | rename 's/.bak/.old/'
```

Comment: This only excludes the _specific_ pathname `./.bak`, but not e.g. `./somefile.bak`.

Answer (score 2):

With a `find` that supports the `-mindepth` predicate:

```
 find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.bak' | rename 's/\.bak$/.old/'
```

The `-mindepth` predicate allows you to define the minimum search depth at which matches can be made.  Depth zero is the root search path itself (`.`), depth 1 is anything immediately under the root search path (e.g. `./somename`), and depth 2 is anything immediately below that (e.g. `./somename/other`), etc.

Note that the caseinsensitive match that `-iname` does is not needed as your `rename` would not rename files that have other types of capitalization of the filename suffix anyway, so I've changed it to a `-name` test instead. I've also fixed your `rename` call so that files with the string `bak` elsewhere in the name, like `rebak.bak`, is not rename in strange ways (e.g. into `r.old.bak`).

I've also added `-type f` to only make `find` consider regular files, i.e. not directories etc.

For a more portable solution:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.bak' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv "$pathname" "${pathname%.bak}.old"
    done' sh {} +
```

This does not rely on the `rename` utilitiy.

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.bak' -exec rename 's/\.bak$/.old/' {} +
```

This calls `rename` directly from `find`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

With `bash`, you can skip `find` altogether and instead do

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob

rename 's/\.bak$/.old/' ./*/**/*.bak
```

The `**` globbing pattern matches any number of intermediate subdirectories. 
 This special pattern is enabled with the `globstar` shell option.  The initial `./*/` makes sure that we only look in subdirectories of the current directory, and not in the current directory itself.

The `dotglob` shell option makes sure that we match hidden names with the pattern.

The above would however not pick out regular files exclusively (but neither does your `find` command). To do that, use a loop:

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob

for pathname in ./*/**/*.bak; do
    [[ ! -f $pathname ]] && continue
    rename 's/\.bak$/.old/' "$pathname"
done
```

This would also rename symbolic links to regular files.